# Window.open, while loop and window.close

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, window, xul

I have a problem with my firefox extension. I'm doing an extension that download a webpage, save it as PDF and then, it upload the file in a server. The problem is here:

```
var myWindow = window.open('chrome://xulschoolhello/content/progressmeter.xul',
'',' top=100, left=100, height=20, width=130');                            
while(file.exists() == false) {         
}     
myWindow.close();
```

To upload the file, I need that the file exists so, I have to wait until it exists. So, I made a progress meter, to show that it's in progress but the extesion has to check if the file exists. The while loop can't be empty, and I were trying a lot of thing to keep it cheack without a firefox crash. Any idea? Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is the code:

```
var myInterval = setInterval((function(){
    if (file.exists()) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        continues();
    }
}),1000);

function continues(){}
```

Every one second, it checks if the file exits, instead of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the a = 10 in the below with your file check.

```
function test() {
    var a = 0;
    function rep() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            a++;
            if (a < 10) {
                rep();
                console.log("a" + a);
            } else {
                console.log("ending a" + a);
            }
        },300);
    }

    rep();
}
```

test();